# Most general conditions for variable substitution with Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, change-of-variable

This question is motivated by the discussion here:

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26687/117

Let $g$ be defined and differentiable on an interval containing $[a,b]$ and $f$ be defined on an interval containing the image of $g$.

What are the most general conditions on $f$ and $g$ so that the change of variables theorem holds?

$$
\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x) \textrm{ d}x = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) \textrm{ d}u
$$

Many textbooks list conditions like "$f$ is continuous and $g$ is continuously differentiable".

I can prove it also in the case "$f$ is Riemann integrable, $g'$ continuously differentiable and monotone."

Do we in fact have it in the more general case "$f$ is Riemann integrable, $g'$ is Riemann integrable"?

If not, I would be grateful for a counterexample.  It would also be nice to have a list of various ways to loosen the conditions in various directions.

Comment: Even more general:  is this theorem valid as long as both integrands are integrable?  It is conceivable that $f(g(x))g'(x)$ could be integrable even when $g'$ is not.

Comment: I guess the "minimal" assumption is that $g$ be absolutely continuous. Otherwise, just having an integrable $g'$ leaves us open to counterexamples involving the devil's staircase ($g'=0$, $g$ is monotone).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Well, strictly speaking (with the Cantor function) $g'$ doesn't exist as a literal derivative at every point on the interval, which is implicit in a fundamental theorem of calculus-type theorem

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I added a clarification that $g$ should be differentiable where it is defined.

Comment: [Here is a relevant paper.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-22/issue-1/A-change-of-variables-theorem-for-the-Riemann-integral/rae/1338515231.pdf) Sarkhel and Výborný show that, when $g’$ is Riemann integrable, the formula holds if either (i) $f$ is Riemann integrable or (ii) $(f \circ g)g’$ is Riemann integrable and $f$ is bounded on the image of $g|_{[a,b]}$. Interestingly, (i) does not hold when considering Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: @JustinHancock This looks great!  You could post it as an answer.  I will need to take some time to verify the paper before accepting.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is just my functional analytic bias, but I'm a bit confused by the focus on the Riemann integral, which seems to make the question (and its answers) more technical than necessary. If one uses the Lebesgue integral instead, the formula holds whenever $f \in L^\infty((a,b))$ and $g \in W^{1,1}((a,b))$, which seems to be as good as one could possibly hope for. Am I missing something that explains why the question and all the comments and answers seem to focus on the Riemann integral?

Comment: @JochenGlueck The question arose in the context of posing a question in a Calc 1 class, where we would be using the Riemann integral.  I don't think the answer to this question would be especially useful for applications (either theoretically or practically).  It is more idle curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the traditional formulation, the change of variables formula is

$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u =
 \int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{1}\label{trad}$$
We typically assume that $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. With the additional assumption that $g'$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, the fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that $g$ is an indefinite integral of $g'$, so we have the following broader formulation.

Let $g$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and let $G$ be an indefinite integral of $g$ on $[a,b]$, i.e. $G(t)=c+\int_a^t g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$. The change of variables formula is then

$$\int_{G(a)}^{G(b)} f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u =
 \int_a^b f(G(x))g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{2}\label{formula}$$

[Kestelman (1961)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3614764) is attributed with the proof of \eqref{formula} when $f$ is Riemann integrable on $G([a,b])$.

The other direction is attributed to [Preiss and Uher (1970)](https://eudml.org/doc/19168). If $f$ is bounded on $G([a,b])$ and $(f \circ G)g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, then \eqref{formula} holds.

[Sarkhel and Výborný (1996/1997)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-22/issue-1/A-change-of-variables-theorem-for-the-Riemann-integral/rae/1338515231.full) and [Tandra (2015)](https://doi-org.ezp-prod1.hul.harvard.edu/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.8.795) present alternative proofs of equivalent formulations. Tandra (2015) replaces the assumption that $G$ is an indefinite integral of $g$ with the assumption that $G$ is Lipschitz continuous and $G'=g$ almost everywhere, in the spirit of the traditional formulation.

[Kuleshov (2021)](https://doi.org/10.3390/math9161899) weakens the condition in Preiss and Uher's result that $f$ must be bounded on $G([a,b])$ to boundedness of $f$ on $[G(a),G(b)]$.

Answer (score 3):

The theorem holds - for a Riemann integral - when both sides are defined and when $f$ is antidifferentiable. If $g$ is **everywhere** differentiable and $(f\circ g)\cdot g'$ and $f$ are both Riemann integrable then the following Riemann integrals exist (by definition) and agree: $$\int_a^b(f\circ g)g'=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f$$

The proof is simple; let $F$ be any primitive for $f$. $F\circ g$ is a primitive for $(f\circ g)g'$ so by one of the fundamental theorems of calculus we get the LHS to (exist and equal) $F(g(b))-F(g(a))$ which is precisely the RHS (by the other fundamental theorem of calculus).

Note $(1)$: We don't always use $u$-substitution quite in the way given by the above. If we recognise our integrand as of the form $(f\circ g)g'$ then by "letting $u=g(x)$", all is well. But, it is very common to instead have an integrand just of the form "$f$" and we let $u=g(x)$... and actually we try to invert this. Stronger hypotheses are needed in that case, namely that $g$ is invertible and its inverse is (i) differentiable (ii) $(f\circ g^{-1})(g^{-1})'$ is Riemann integrable. Things can easily go wrong, for instance it is not so uncommon for students to do something like this:

> $$\frac{2}{3}=\int_{-1}^1x^2\,\mathrm{d}x\overset{u=x^2}{\underset{???}{=}}\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{3}$$

Note $(2)$: to extend this in general to Lebesgue integration (taking $f$ to be Lebesgue but not Riemann integrable, e.g.) is subtle. There is a change-of-variables formula similar to this: $$\int_{[a,b]}(f\circ g)|g'|=\int_{g([a,b])}f$$In the instance that $g$ is $C^1$ with nonvanishing derivative and $f$ is in $L^1$. Note the absolute value $|g'|$; Lebesgue integrals don't have the same orientation concerns that Riemann integrals do. However there are also Lebesgue-integral forms of the classical FTC (see Rudin):

> $$f(b)-f(a)=\int_{[a,b]}f'$$Either when: (i) $f$ is absolutely continuous (thus $f'$ exists a.e.) and (ii) $f'$ is in $L^1[a,b]$ or when: (i) $f$ is differentiable *everywhere* and (ii) $f'$ is in $L^1[a,b]$

Working with this, we recover the Riemann change of variables formula: $$\int_a^b(f\circ g)g'=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f$$If in your situation we have that $f$ and $(f\circ g)g'$ are both in $L^1$ and either: (i) $g$ is absolutely continuous and $f$ has an absolutely continuous (a.e.)-antiderivative or (ii): $f$ has an (everywhere-)antiderivative and $g$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: I agree that if $f$ has a primitive then we can use the fundamental theorem to give a simple argument.  It does not answer my question about whether the theorem is valid when we only know that $f$ and $g'$ are Riemann integrable:  many Riemann integrable functions do not have a primitive.

Comment: @StevenGubkin It doesn’t answer it, no. I have merely written up the strongest theorems which I know of. The generic change of variables typically assumes $g$ is C^1 and probably there is a known counterexample justifying this

Comment: See Justin Hancock's linked paper on the OP.  Seems that a quite general conditions can be established!  Still need to verify the paper is correct (will take a look later today after farm work is accomplished).

Comment: @StevenGubkin Justin's post is interesting, but I note a subtle difference; there is no reason to suppose that $G'=g$ in his formulation of the problem, so we aren't quite looking at $\int f=\int(f\circ g)g'$

Comment: @FShrike An equivalent formulation to $G$ being an indefinite integral of $g$ is $G$ is Lipschitz continuous and $G'=g$ almost everywhere!

Comment: @FShrike Actually, if $g'$ defined on $[a,b]$ and is Riemann integrable, then $G(x) = \int_a^x g'(t) \textrm{ d}t = g(x) - g(a)$, so it seems that the results he mentions do apply to my situation.  The results generalize, rather than restrict, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @StevenGubkin you have referred to $G,g,g’$ which is too many things. Justin’s $G$ is my $g$ and their $g$ is my $g’$. $G$ an indefinite integral for $g$ doesn’t mean $G’=g$ “on the nose”, this could fail to be true on a null but nonempty set. But nonetheless you are right that their situation is more general. I noticed it was different but didn’t notice it was more general at first

Comment: @FShrike It was a bit awkwardly notated, but my point was that (in the notation of my original question):  if $g'$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and Riemann integrable then $g(x) = g(a) + \int_a^x g'(t) \textrm{d}t$ by the fundamental theorem.  Hence the results Justin presents are applicable at the level of generality I originally requesed.